# How to embed terminal (without using Glue) in SublimeText 3

Tags: terminal, ide, editor, sublimetext

I really just want my terminal embedded directly in SublimeText 3. 90% of what I use other IDE's for is just the terminal embed. How do I just get a live terminal instance embedded in my editor that I can manipulate? Note: I've used the Glue plugin before and I have not been that impressed...

Comment: I looked for this for a long time about a year ago and was not able to find a solution, sadly.

Comment: The sadness is so real. I just want to be able to do a Rubymine style file find and a terminal window. >.<

Comment: If you just need your terminal for running your specs, you could look at RubyTest.

Comment: I just want a live terminal. I wanna do more than just run specs (rails server, migrations, asset serving, foreman, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I got what I wanted out of the SublimeREPL plugin! You can just use the REPL with Bash and it works just like a regular terminal, you may have to fiddle with some of the path variables though.